# Django cannot find the djangular/app.js file via the urls.py config. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, python, django, configuration, djangular

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out and it's driving me up the wall. I'm limited on what I can copy and paste, so forgive the 'code brevity'. I also have a working version I developed and have uploaded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/ancientswordrage/nwod-db).

I'm developing a Django website that also uses AngularJS, so I'm using the [`djangular`](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular) package, specifically the bit that lets me import Django variables into Angular. [This](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular#including-some-django-template-like-features-in-your-angularjs-templates) is the section from GitHub:

> To use the AngularJS module that Djangular provides you, you'll need to add the djangular app to your projects URLs.
>
> ```
>  urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       ...
>       url(r'^djangular/', include('djangular.urls')),
>       ...
>   )
> ```

And I've placed this in my `project/urls.py` file. I've done the same with my GitHub repository.

When I reference that URL in my `appName/app/index.html`, I do so like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'djangular/app.js' %}"></script>
```

But that leads to a 500 response from the server as Angular produces the *Module 'djangular' is not available!* error. What should be happening is that the URL `djangular/app.js` in the script tag above, should redirect to `urls.py` inside the Djangular folder in the Python `site-packages`, which then points to `DjangularModuleTemplateView.as_view()`. This seems to work in my GitHub version, but not in the local version I have for some reason.

If I have my script tag without the `"{%static '...'%}"` part I still get a 500, with the same error:

```
<script src="/djangular/app.js"></script>
```

What config could I possibly have overlooked that's causing the app not to find the right Djangular config? I've stared at both configurations so long my eyes are glazing over, and I'm struggling to find any differences. What else could it be?

I'm more than happy to provide more details if needed to answer this question.

Comment: I've also noticed that in [this](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular#using-django-templates-to-render-the-skeleton-of-the-app) example, the static variable isn't used at all.

Comment: I've solved this by syncing the DB (`./manage.py syncdb`) but it has also stopped the server serving any other files (I don't even get 404s). The terminal doesn't display any of the requests. Once I fix that, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself by running ./manage syncdb

This creates various tables (the user table, and the session table at least) which are required for Djangular to run.

Then I double checked all my `<script>` imports/includes.